# Remove html tags from a corpus in R

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, information-retrieval

I am trying to remove the html tag from a corpus (docs) in R:

```
tags : </P></TEXT>  </BODY> <TRAILER> NYT-06-22-98 1759EDT &QL; </TRAILER> </DOC>
```

The code I am using:

```
tun<-function(x) gsub("<TRAILER>,<HTML>,<BODY>,<P>,<TEXT>,</P>,</TEXT>,
</BODY>,</HTML>", "", x)
docs <- tm_map(docs, tun)
```

But its not able to remove the tags from the corpus , why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all opening and closing HTML tags, then you may try finding the pattern `</?[^>]+>` and replacing with empty string:

```
x <- "tags : </P></TEXT>  </BODY> <TRAILER> NYT-06-22-98 1759EDT &QL; </TRAILER> </DOC>"
gsub("</?[^>]+>", "", x)


[1] "tags :     NYT-06-22-98 1759EDT &QL;  "
```

### Demo

As a major disclaimer, in general you should *not* use regex to parse HTML/XML content.  In this particular case, if you just want to strip off all tags, `gsub` may be a viable option.

Comment: yes I just wanted to strip off all tags from the documents. Thank you.

Comment: @akrun You're right, it's a dupe, I didn't think to check.  Bad on me.